# get a sequence of more than X spaces considered as an empty column while there are sometimes two spaces to separate two columns

Tags: linux, awk

To use the data from a publisher software, I have functions that I can call via the CLI (Linux Shell).

One of them returns the data to me with the following format:

```
2601424 OPTDCBO3 EERP O 0254  5512240 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2602451 WHA      EERP O 0254  5512353 03ZEE003 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2602748 OPTDCBO4 EERP O 0254  5512380 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2603290 OPTDCBO3 EERP O 0254  5512440 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2604594 OPTDCBO3 EERP O 0254  5512560 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2605631 OP49LDB1 TRAN O 0254          EDRZZZ02 B     2605627-EDR 00 0000000 N  N
2605657 OP49LDB1 TRAN O 0254          EDRZZZ02 B     2605652-EDR 00 0000000 N  N
2605663 OP49LDB1 TRAN O 0254          EDRZZZ02 B     2605653-EDR 00 0000000 N  N
2606116 OPTDCBO3 EERP O 0254  5513080 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2716077 OPTDCBO3 EERP O 0255  5610080 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2716564 SOG01    TRAN O 0255 s2716564 TACSOG01 B     2716504-TAC 00 0000000 N  N
2718631 OPTDCBO3 EERP O 0255  5610160 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
7158273 OPTDCBO4 EERP O 0251  5203300 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
7158672 WHA      EERP O 0251  5203342 03ZEE001 B                 00 0000000 N  N
7158939 ZZZA4    LIST O 0251                   B     7158938-49W 00 0000000 N  N
7158978 OPTDCBO3 EERP O 0251  5203400 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
7159853 OPTDCBO4 EERP O 0251  5203540 TDCTAC01 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2724704 SOU02    TRAN I 0255 s2724704 FTP_B    E     2724704-SOU 00 0000000 N  N
2724707 PRODS2I  EERP O 0255  6219255 S2IRCE03 E                 00 0000000 N  N
2724708 SOU01    TRAN I 0255 s2724708 FTP_B    E     2724708-SOU 00 0000001 N  N
2724709 SON01    TRAN O 0255 s2724709 SOUSON11 E     2724708-SOU 00 0000001 N  N
```

A space separates the first 5 columns, and one or two spaces separate the 5th and 6th columns.
Sometimes columns 6 and 7 are empty.

The aim is to return part or all of this data in a delimited text file with commas between each field.

To retrieve the 1st and 7th column, I use:

```
command | awk -F" " '{ print $1,$7 }'
```

But it gives:

```
2603290 TDCTAC01
2604594 TDCTAC01
2605631 B
2605657 B
2605663 B
2606116 TDCTAC01
2606214 TDCTAC01
7158672 03ZEE001
7158939 7158938-49W
7158978 TDCTAC01
```

Awk considers columns filled with spaces as a multitude of adjacent separators and not as an empty column and therefore returns the data of the following non-empty column.

How do I get a sequence of more than X spaces considered as an empty column while there are sometimes two spaces to separate two columns?

Column N°6 can be composed of 1 to 6 numeric characters, so you cannot simply use a fixed width to delimit the column.

Comment: Have a look at [`FIELDWIDTHS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fixed-width-data) which is part of GNU Awk. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

wrt `Column N°6 can be composed of 1 to 6 numeric characters, so you cannot simply use a fixed width to delimit the column.` - sure you can. The width of that column is fixed at a width of 8 chars (or 9 to lazily include the separator space) - use that and trim leading/trailing white space (`gsub(/^ +| +/,"",$6)`) to be left with the value you're interested in.

Here's how to identify all the fields using GNU awk for `FIELDWIDTHS` (with other awks you need a `while(substr())` loop):

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="7 9 5 2 5 9 9 2 16 3 8 2 3" '
{
    print "----"
    print $0
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$i)
        print i, "<" $i ">"
    }
}
' file
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
2602451 WHA      EERP O 0254  5512353 03ZEE003 B                 00 0000000 N  N
2605657 OP49LDB1 TRAN O 0254          EDRZZZ02 B     2605652-EDR 00 0000000 N  N
2724704 SOU02    TRAN I 0255 s2724704 FTP_B    E     2724704-SOU 00 0000000 N  N
```

.

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="7 9 5 2 5 9 9 2 16 3 8 2 3" '{ print "----"; print $0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i); print i, "<" $i ">"} }' file
----
2602451 WHA      EERP O 0254  5512353 03ZEE003 B                 00 0000000 N  N
1 <2602451>
2 <WHA>
3 <EERP>
4 <O>
5 <0254>
6 <5512353>
7 <03ZEE003>
8 <B>
9 <>
10 <00>
11 <0000000>
12 <N>
13 <N>
----
2605657 OP49LDB1 TRAN O 0254          EDRZZZ02 B     2605652-EDR 00 0000000 N  N
1 <2605657>
2 <OP49LDB1>
3 <TRAN>
4 <O>
5 <0254>
6 <>
7 <EDRZZZ02>
8 <B>
9 <2605652-EDR>
10 <00>
11 <0000000>
12 <N>
13 <N>
----
2724704 SOU02    TRAN I 0255 s2724704 FTP_B    E     2724704-SOU 00 0000000 N  N
1 <2724704>
2 <SOU02>
3 <TRAN>
4 <I>
5 <0255>
6 <s2724704>
7 <FTP_B>
8 <E>
9 <2724704-SOU>
10 <00>
11 <0000000>
12 <N>
13 <N>
```

Comment: does this mean you need to know how many spaces are between each column `FIELDWIDTHS="7 9 5 2 5 9 9 2 16 3 8 2 3` e.g. 7 spaces between column 1 and column 2? or i don't understand you numbers in quotes? @ed

Comment: Not quite, it's saying that field 1 is 7 chars wide then field 2 is 9 chars wide, etc. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size for an explanation.