# using OFS with awk on file with multiple spaces as delimiter

Tags: awk

I have file with multiple spaces as the delimiter.

```
> cat file1.csv
col1 col2  col3   col4
col1 col2  col3
col1   col2
col1
col1  col2   col3   col4   col5
```

This is the output I want but with no empty new lines (which makes me wonder if my `-F' {2,}'` is working)

```
> awk -F' {2,}' 'NR==1{print $0}' file1.csv | tr " " "\n"
col1
col2

col3


col4
>
```

But I was hoping to do it  with AWK and using the OFS, but not sure if doing it right

```
> awk -F' {2,}' 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR==1{print $0}' file1.csv
col1 col2  col3   col4
```

### Other work in this space for my ref

```
I want to do something like this but with 

>cat file.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
col1,col2,col3
col1,col2
col1
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

> awk -F, 'NR==1{print $0}' file.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4

> awk -F, 'NR==1{print $0}' file.csv | tr "," "\n"
col1
col2
col3
col4
> awk -F, 'NR==1{print $0}' file.csv | tr "," "\n" | cat -n
     1  col1
     2  col2
     3  col3
     4  col4




I can just use sed to remove blank lines but I want to use awk OFS as above: 
> awk -F' {2,}' 'NR==1{print $0}' file1.csv | tr " " "\n" | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
col1
col2
col3
col4
>
```

Comment: `head -n 1 file1.csv | tr -s ' ' '\n'`; `head -n 1 file.csv | tr , '\n'`

Comment: Don't say `This is the output I want but with no empty new lines` and then show output that includes empty lines - just show the exact output you want so your needs are clear and explicit and we can copy/paste it to test with.

Comment: Regarding `-F' {2,}'` - that's not going to do anything different than the default `FS` would do for your posted input, what problem in your real data are you trying to solve by using that FS (e.g. do you have fields that can contain blanks)?

Comment: Piping awk output to tr, sed, etc. is never necessary.

Comment: Is this question related to your question in a comment yesterday about fixed width fields - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292868/awk-and-multiple-spaces-column-delimiters/52295710?noredirect=1#comment132789168_52295710?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
$ head file?.csv
==> file1.csv <==
col1 col2  col3   col4
col1 col2  col3
col1   col2
col1
col1  col2   col3   col4   col5

==> file2.csv <==
col1,col2,col3,col4
col1,col2,col3
col1,col2
col1
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

You can use `head` and `sed`.

For a space / tab separated file:

```
$ head -1 file1.csv | sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]{1,}/\n/g'
col1
col2
col3
col4
```

Comma separated:

```
$ head -1 file2.csv | sed -E 's/,/\n/g'
col1
col2
col3
col4
```

You can also skip `head` altogether and use `sed` to 1) find line `n`, 2) do the replacement; 3) quit. Here for the fifth line:

```
sed -nE '5{s/([[:blank:]]{1,})/\n/g; p; q; }' file1.csv
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
```

Just use `1` for the first line.

Or similarly with `awk`:

```
$ awk -v ln=5 -F"[[:blank:]]{1,}" 'FNR==ln{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i; exit}' file1.csv
```

Comment: `head -1 file1.csv | sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]{1,}/\n/g' ` what is -E and and does this replace blank spaces of 1 or more with \n?

Comment: `-E` means use extended regular expressions;  `[[:blank:]]` is a horizontal space (`' '` or `\t`) and the 1 or more spaces is `{1,}`

Answer (score 4):

Assumptions:

- we're only interested in the 1st line of the file
- each field/column of the (1st) line is to be printed on a separate line

Sample inputs:

```
$ head file?.csv
==> file1.csv <==
col1 col2  col3   col4
col1 col2  col3
col1   col2
col1
col1  col2   col3   col4   col5

==> file2.csv <==
col1,col2,col3,col4
col1,col2,col3
col1,col2
col1
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

For the 1st file (`file1.csv`) we can use the default input field delimiter (ie, white space):

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i; exit}' file1.csv
col1
col2
col3
col4
```

For the 2nd file (`file2.csv`) we use an input field delimiter of a comma (`,`):

```
$ awk -F',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i; exit}' file2.csv
col1
col2
col3
col4
```

**NOTE:** in neither of these cases do we need to worry setting the output field separator (`OFS`)

---

If we absolutely, positively need to set, and use, a non-default `OFS`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {$1=$1; print; exit}' file1.csv                            
col1
col2
col3
col4

$ awk -F',' 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"} {$1=$1; print; exit}' file2.csv
col1
col2
col3
col4
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna de-dupe it all down to `col1` to `col5`, try :

```
     1  col1 col2  col3   col4
     2  col1 col2  col3
     3  col1   col2
     4  col1
     5  col1  col2   col3   col4   col5
     6  col1,col2,col3,col4
     7  col1,col2,col3
     8  col1,col2
     9  col1
    10  col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
```

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk '!__[$0]++' RS='[,[:space:]]+'
> ```

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
```

Comment: tks but what command do ir ? `{m,g,n}awk '!__[$0]++' RS='[,[:space:]]+'`

Comment: @HattrickNZ : basic deduping, but using any one of `space \horizontal-tab \newline \vertical-tab \form-feed \carriage-return and comma` (plus a few unicode spaces that you'll rarely encounter) to delimit the "rows"